# How does one print either a A, B, or a * character in a Row*Column rectangle only a given percentage of a time?

Tags: java, printf, computer-science, nested-loops

So using a for loop inside a for loop, one can print a rectangle given that we have rows and columns.

For example,

```
  int rows = 5;
  int cols = 5;
  double rand = Math.random() * 100;

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
     }
     System.out.println(" ");
  }
```

the output being

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

How does one print a character such that instead of an asterisk, we can have the asterisk be replaced either by a letter A, B, or an asterisk ("*"). To make it even more difficult, let's say the probability that in place for the asterisk that there will be a  letter "A" 60% of the time, the letter B, 30% of the time, and the "*" only 10% of the time?

I was thinking maybe something like this. Is my logic correct, what can I do to change this?:

```
        double rand = Math.random() * 100;

        if (rand < 30) { 
           System.out.print("C");
        }
        if (rand < 10 && rand > 0) {
           System.out.print("H");
        }
        if (rand < 60 && rand > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are on the right track, **but** you should test the least condition first (because 10 is also less than 30) **and** you should be using `else`. Something like

```
double rand = Math.random() * 100;
if (rand < 10) {
   System.out.print("*"); // <-- 10 percent of the time
} else if (rand < 40) {   // <-- 10 + 30 = 40
   System.out.print("B"); // <-- 30 percent of the time.
} else {
   System.out.print("A"); // <-- 100 - 40 = 60
}
```